# What's my PhD status after I passed my oral defense (UK)?

Tags: phd, united-kingdom

I'm applying for a postdoc. I passed my PhD viva in the UK, and was given minor corrections which I've submitted. What is my status? Can I say PhD (pass)? Or something better?

Comment: "PhD (completed viva on xxx, scheduled to get the diploma on yyy)" or something similar is the most accurate description. It won't last, anyway.

Comment: I believe it is "PhD candidate"

Comment: @TheFireGuy Use of the term "PhD candidate" is pretty rare in the UK, and then only as a synonym for PhD student. Normally, PhD candidate refers to someone who has passed US-style qualifying exams, which do not exist in the UK. I don't think this term applies here.

Comment: @MJeffryes, I did not know that! Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: (In the US) I am not certain that one should write anything other than "PhD. Myschool University 2010-2016 (expected.)". Any offer you get is likely assuming (or perhaps not even caring in some circumstances) you will get your degree in the appropriate time frame. Adding mess to a CV to explain a situation every member on a hiring committee should already understand seems silly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is always a tricky time period. Trying to make such a complicated situation clear in a single line on your CV is impossible. Write something on your CV that suggests that you have not completed your PhD yet (you do not want to mislead people), but that you are very far along (submitted, defended, passed with minor corrections, etc). Then in your cover letter use a sentence or two to explain the the situation. For example:

> My thesis on Under Water Basket Weaving was approved by my examining committee and my PhD will be awarded in May 2016. I have already published 6 articles from the thesis and based on discussions during my viva voce, I am currently revising portions of the dissertation for 2 further publications.

Comment: This is nice phrasing. But I am surprised if you got 8 papers from the PhD thesis!

Comment: @StopUsingFacebook I am surprised you don't know that under water basket weavers are prolific publishers.

Comment: @StopUsingFacebook Maybe if you stop using Facebook you would have 8 papers :p

Answer (score 3):

If you have completed all the requirements for a degree but your degree has not yet formally been conferred by the university then you are a *graduand*. This term is not used very often but it is technically correct for both the UK and US systems. For some examples of its use see https://www.google.co.uk/#q=graduand+site:ac.uk (UK university websites) and https://www.google.co.uk/#q=graduand+site:edu (US university websites).

It's also worth noting that as [Yemon Choi's answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/68228/52346) points out, at some universities your degree might have been considered to have been conferred automatically when your corrections were accepted (in which case allow me to be the first to congratulate you, Dr StopUsingFacebook!).

Answer (score 1):

All of what follows applies only to the UK context, since that is the one mentioned by the OP.

This is not exactly on-topic, but I thought it should be pointed out: for certain bureaucratic purposes, you may wish to find out from your university exactly when the PhD is "officially conferred", once you have had your corrections approved. The date of conferral *might* affect things like cut-off-dates for grants, although I do not know of actual cases where anyone lost out because of this.

For instance, I think in some places they might now use the date of the "congregation" a.k.a. graduation ceremony as the date on which the PhD is conferred. On the other hand, I recently had cause to double-check the rule at the place where I received my PhD, and found that according to the rules at the time

> ... a Newcastle University qualification is deemed to be conferred on publication of the pass list. The degree is no longer conferred at a University congregation, and the date which appears on the parchment is the date of the pass list, not the date of a Congregation.

Presumably by now you'll have been put on the pass list and notified.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question

Comment: @StrongBad Fair enough: it was intended to answer what I thought was a secondary underlying question from the OP, about what to put on the CV etc about when you can say you have received the PhD.

Answer (score 1):

Have you received a notice that your corrections have been approved and you have fully passed?

If not I would suggest putting something like.

PhD <subject> (passed subject to minor corrections)

If your corrections have been officially approved I think you are safe just mentiong the PhD without further comment on it's status.